# Hibernate and infinite loop - duplicate entries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm having some trouble with work-related issue:

There's a business requirement to actively receive datagram packets via multicast (which in this case means we're using while (true) loop).

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
while (true) {
  receivePacket();
  parsePacket();
  saveParsedPacketToDatabase();
}
```

We're using Spring Data JPA to save entities to database - this is the component making inserts:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class InsertService {

    @Inject
    private DataRepository dataRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public void saveParsedPacketToDatabase(List<Data> data) {
        dataRepository.save(data);
        dataRepository.flush();
    }
}
```

The Data object containts Date field, let's say insertTime set on **@PrePersist/Update**:

```
@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
void preSave() {
    insertTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDate();
}
```

Now the problem is we are getting 2 identical objects (all fields are the same **BUT** insertTime and generated id. **Important thing - insertTime differences are milliseconds, no more than 100**) for every inserted entity.

I've been trying to debug this thing and find what the issue is but I have no clue.. We definitely are not getting duplicate data via multicast and I think there might be something wrong with the inserting techinique.. Skipping infinite loop is not an option - maybe there's a need to queue things somehow..

I'd definitely appreciate any help,

Cheers,
Marcin

Comment: what is the application server. Is there any retry logic for it. Sometimes application server admin will configure retry logic if some transaction fails at server level.

Comment: We're using Apache Tomcat with pretty much default configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing around with it for a while and I realized (by debugging hibernate inserts) that I didn't say the important part here: I've been using Spring's **ApplicationEventPublisher** interface to publish business events.

The whole thing was somewhere in between of **receivePacket()** and **parsePacket()** methods.

I realized that ApplicationEventPublisher's **publishEvent** method is **making database inserts** - I'm not sure yet why it's doing this - I'm guessing that somewhere in Spring's Data code there's something listening - I'll try to localize the source when I'll have more time - for now I'm glad I got it working.

Sorry for not providing relevant information; I hope someone will make use of this information in the future.

Best,
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue to this earlier this year. Firstly get rid of your entire `preSave()` method. `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` are rubbish, not (supposed to be) supported by Hibernate 4 and will cause you more headaches than you can imagine. I know this because this is the original route I took when trying to solve this issue.

I'm going to assume you are using a MySQL database or similar, but any decent RDBMS should be able to handle what I'm proposing.

To solve this issue what you want to do is annotate the `insertTime` field with `@Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)`. This basically says to your database 'whenever this record is inserted, generate a value for this field'.

In your database you assign a default value to the column that represents `insertTime` that is whatever the current time is. Most RDBMS's support such things, my HSQL table declaration for such a field is `dateModified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW` but you may have to check depending on which database type you are using. This should set the insertTime value whenever you insert it into the database. As a precaution, if my `@Generated` fields have a value, I just set them too null to ensure that there is nothing going in, and any value that comes out must have been set by the database.

If this doesn't work or you need more explanation let me know.

Comment: I did remove the annotations (that resulted in nullifying the field, but it was just the test) - we are still getting double entries for each inserted row